# why a nested element is selected by last-of-type?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

I have a very simple HTML structure as shown in the following:

```
<div>
    <div>a<div>a1</div></div>
    <div>b</div>
    <p>c</p>
    <div>d</div>
</div>
```

And `document.body.querySelector('div > div:last-of-type')` returns `<div>a1</div>`, not `<div>d</div>`.

I thought `document.body.querySelector('div > div:last-of-type')` should be same to `document.body.querySelector('div > div:nth-of-type(3)')`, which returns `<div>d</div>`.

So to summarize my questions:

1. Why does `document.body.querySelector('div > div:last-of-type')` return `<div>a1</div>`, not `<div>d</div>`? Is it a bug?
2. What is the correct way to select `<div>d</div>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from div children of the initial container div, give the div a class or an ID such as `.container` and then select it as `document.body.querySelector('div.container > div:last-of-type');`

Your current code is selecting from divs that are the last div child of any other div, you aren't specifying that you want to look at exclusively the container div's children

Answer (score 0):

According to the `document#querySelector` [spec](https://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/selectors-api2/#interface-definitions)

> The querySelector() methods on the Document, DocumentFragment, and
>   Element interfaces must return the first matching Element node within
>   the subtrees of the context object.

**What is the 1st matching element?**

We can use `document#uerySelectorAll` with the same selector, and as you can see the 1st result in the array is `<div>a1</div>`.

```js
const result = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('div > div:last-of-type'));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <div>a<div>a1</div></div>
    <div>b</div>
    <p>c</p>
    <div>d</div>
</div>
```

**How can you get the `<div>d</div>`?**

Create a selector that will match only what you want:

```js
console.log(document.body.querySelector('body > div > div:last-of-type'));

console.log(document.body.querySelector('p + div'));
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <div>a<div>a1</div></div>
    <div>b</div>
    <p>c</p>
    <div>d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is the canonical way to get the last child

```js
console.log(document.body.querySelector('div').lastElementChild)
```

```html
<div>
    <div>a<div>a1</div></div>
    <div>b</div>
    <p>c</p>
    <div>d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > Why does `document.body.querySelector('div > div:last-of-type')` return `<div>a1</div>`, not `<div>d</div>`? Is it a bug?

   No, it's not a bug. The reason is twofold:

   1. If a selector matches multiple elements, `querySelector()` returns only the first matching element.
   2. The selector is not scoped to the element whose `querySelector()` method is called.

   Since `<div>a1</div>` is the first element that matches `div > div:last-of-type`, that is what is returned by your code.
2. > What is the correct way to select `<div>d</div>`?

   ```
   document.querySelector('body > div > div:last-of-type')
   ```

   No need to overcomplicate matters.